# How can I combine Flutters ListView.builder with the DataTable, or is there another Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know how to use the ListView.builder and I just now realized that I need 2 columns for my Application. Flutters explanation of the DataTable however didn't seem modular like it could take  values from my stream the same way ListView.builder does. Is this possible and how could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `table widget` for your app.
The first step you must create a title for you table:

```
List<TableRow> rows = [];
rows.add(
  TableRow(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2)),
    children: [
            Text("name"),
            Text("name"),
            Text("name"),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Second Step:

```
    int tabLength = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < tabLength; ++i) {
      rows.add(
        TableRow(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: i % 2 != 0 ? Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.05) : Colors.white,
          ),
          children: [
            Text("name"),
            Text("name"),
            Text("name"),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
```

Third step you can return your table:

```
return Table(
  children: rows,
);
```

The function table:

```
  Widget createTable(List<GetOrderFoodModel> ordersFoods, double totalVal) {
    List<TableRow> rows = [];
    rows.add(
      TableRow(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2)),
        children: [
            Text("name"),
            Text("name"),
            Text("name"),
        ],
      ),
    );    
    int tabLength = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < tabLength; ++i) {
      rows.add(
        TableRow(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: i % 2 != 0 ? Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.05) : Colors.white,
          ),
          children: [
            Text("name"),
            Text("name"),
            Text("name"),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
    rows.add(
      TableRow(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
        ),
        children: [
            Text("name"),
            Text("name"),
            Text("name"),
        ],
      ),
    );

    return Table(
      children: rows,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

here is how to do it:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: widget._returnDataStream(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot < QuerySnapshot > snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    return new DataTable(
      rows: _RowsFromStream(snapshot.data),
    );
  } else {
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
})


List <DataRow> _RowsFromStream(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {

  List <DataRow> newList = snapshot.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    return new DataRow(cells: _createMyCells(documentSnapshot["data"]));
  }).toList();

  return newList;
}
```